# Улучшить результат нейронной сети на Python для решения линейного уравнения

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, numpy, sklearn

Столкнулся с проблемой при написании нейронной сети на Питоне.
Я выбрал себе цель достигнуть получения значения уравнения Y = Ax + B
Где А, х и B - это входные данные, А Y выходные.

Загружаю нужные библиотеки

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor
```

Задаю функцию, с помощью нее я буду формировать входные данные и выходные данные для обучения, то есть здесь будет теоретический(максимально достоверный результат), а не экспериментальный

```
def function(A,B,x):
    Y = A*x + B
    return Y
```

Здесь я с помощью функции рандома задаю A, B, x, то есть входные данные, их я буду далее вставлять в верхнюю функцию и высчитывать выходную Y.

```
x = np.random.randint(-100, 100, 10000)
A = np.random.randint(-100, 100, 10000)
B = np.random.randint(-100,100, 10000)
```

Получаю результат Y

```
Y  = function(A,B,x)
```

Для верной работы нейронной сети транспонирую входные данные

```
X = np.array([x,A,B]).T
```

Выбираю модель нейронной сети

```
mlp =  MLPRegressor(hidden_layer_sizes=(100, 100), tol=1e-2, max_iter=2000, random_state=0)
```

Произвожу обучение

```
mlp.fit(X, Y)
```

Теперь самое главное, я предсказываю данные

```
x_predict = np.array([15,2,3],dtype = int).reshape(1,-1)
mlp.predict(x_predict)
```

Для примера я взял х, А, В = 15, 2, 3. Очевидно, что ответ будет 33
Но нейронная сеть выдает следующий ответ

```
array([-25.81754109])
```

Когда я брал значения, для обучения в интервале (-20, 20), значения получались достаточно близкие, но когда использовал разброс в диапазоне (-100, 100), получается нелепость.

**Следовательно:**
Как мне оптимизировать нейронную сеть? Стоит ли изменить модель или оставить, как есть, только поменяв параметры?
Буду очень рад выслушать вашу критику и советы.

Comment: А какую модель вы строите???  Я к тому, что причем тут задание на вход А и B, да еще и ранодомно в качестве "обучающий примеров". Что-же вы ожидаете получить в результате?

Comment: вы использовали 10000 случайных коэффициентов `A` и `B`, поэтому и модель окажется соответствующей

Comment: @passant Multi-layer Perceptron regressor. Я ожидаю получить Y, очевидно. Введя  при этом x a b. При значениях -20, 20 точность боле менее адекватная, а вот при другом радиусе значений - все очень плохо.

Comment: @MaxU А как исправить, чтобы были адекватные числа?

Comment: @steam-ilka, сначала определитесь с задачей ;) Если вы хотите найти коэффициенты линейного уравнения, то и точки обучающего набора надо строить так, чтобы они образовывали некое облако вокруг некоторой прямой. А еще лучше скачать один из готовых наборов данных и строить модель на этих данных. PS использовать MLP для нахождения коэффициентов линейного уравнения - это как из пушки по воробьям :-D

Comment: @А что использовать вместо MLP? Мне нужно конкретно нейронная сеть.
И можете еще пояснить конкретно  "некого облака вокруг некоторой прямой" немного непонятно.

Comment: А вы попробуйте хоть что-то прочитать про нейронные сети и как они строят модели. Для вашего случая входом для fit есть вектор X и вектор Y. Результат - модель, т.е. коэффициенты A и B. Что-бы это работало, генерировать в вашей тестовой функции  надо  Y=A*X+B+e, где случайные величины это X и ошибка e.  А "А" и "В" при этом фиксированы. Тогда и будет у вас "облако", о котором упомянул коллега.

Comment: @passant,я понял свою ошибку. Теперь все верно. Система предсказывает, какие могут быть коэффициенты при различных Х и У, спасибо.
Но я использовал MLP, хотья MaxU сказал, что это неверно. Почему регрессор здесь не подходит? Какую модель выбрать, чтобы получить более точные значения?

Comment: @steam-ilka  MaxU- очень граммотный специалист. Поэтому он сказал - дословно - "использовать MLP для нахождения коэффициентов линейного уравнения - это как из пушки по воробьям".  Про "неверно" тут ничего на написано. А сказал он так - могу только догадываться - потому, как строить ЛИНЕЙНУЮ ОДНОМЕРНУЮ РЕГРЕССИОННУЮ модель с помощью MLP -  это как решать задачу на скорость движения пешехода с помощью уравнений квантовой физики. Можно конечно, но в общем - "из пушки по воробьям", да. А модель выберите элементарную - "линейная регрессия".

Comment: @passant, спасибо. Но мне нужно использовать именно нейронные сети для решения данного вопроса. Обычное МО мне, к сожалению, использовать нельзя.

Comment: @steam-ilka  -  ну дело ваше. Если это учебное задание. Хотя даже в этом случае я не понимаю. Если бы вы сами писали сеть - тогда понятно. НТипа написать самому самую простую сетку. А так, используется готовое решения. Какая разница какие? Впрочем - пусть ваш лектор про это думает.